# Dataset for DBpedia YAGO classes?

Tags: java, jena, dbpedia

I have this code:

```
String NS="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/";
model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
model.read("dbpedia.owl");
```

But this ontology (dbpedia.owl) is based only on the classes whose URIs begin with `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`. I would also like to add the classes whose URIs begin with `http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you've just downloaded the [DBpedia Ontology T-BOX (Schema)](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.9/dbpedia_3.9.owl.bz2).

On the [Downloads page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39), there are links to more datasets.  Under [Links to other datasets](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39#h16052-1) there are four YAGO related datasets:

- YAGO links
- YAGO type links
- YAGO types
- YAGO type hierarchy

The description of the YAGO type hierarchy is:

> #### YAGO type hierarchy
>
> Dataset containing the hierarchy of [YAGO](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/) classes in the http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/ namespace. Update mechanism: [generated from latest YAGO datasets](https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/blob/dump/scripts/src/main/bash/process-yago.txt).

I think it's that dataset that will contain what you're looking for, though I do suggest you look at the other ones too, in case there's something useful in there.

Comment: Thanks Joshua ( Excuse me for a lot of asks...But Jena and Semantic web are new for me) . Well, I downloaded the file .nt ...No How could I add it to the old model?

Comment: @user2837896 `model.read` adds statements to the model.  If you do `model.read("dbpedia.owl"); model.read("yago_taxonomy.nt");`, then `model` will contain the contents of both.

Comment: At model.read("yago_taxonomy.nt") I receive this error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: @user2837896 Yup, there's lots of data there.  Try giving your JVM more memory, I guess.

Comment: How Could I Do ? And How Can I see the current value of memory?

Comment: I modified the file eclipse.ini with
-Xms500m
-Xmx1g
but I have the same result

Comment: It could be that it's too big to hold conveniently in memory.  You might look into using Jena's TDB, which stores data on disk (but you still get to have Jena `Model`s, &c.).  There are some questions on StackOverflow that might help:  [Querying large RDF Datasets out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17005778/1281433); [Host DBpedia locally for categories](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15417828/1281433) (not all that useful); the second half of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16610663/1281433); [Jena TDB to store and query using API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11101757/1281433).